# How can I create an annotation that evaluates a condition

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, annotations

A Scenario

```
@FeatureToggle(variable == True) 
functionCall(a,b,c); // call skipped if variable is False
```

Is this something easily achievable?
I would rather not want to use some 3rd party solution.

I am well aware that this is possible with a simple IF condition but still.

Comment: An annotation doesn't do anything, an annotation is merely metadata. You still need a processor (either compile or runtime) to know what to do what that annotation.

Comment: With Spring AOP , the call to the method `functionCall()` can be controlled based on the `variable` value.